# What is an "Options Account"?

Tags: roth-ira, options

I am filling out the form to apply for a TDAmeritrade Minor Roth IRA. I understand what's going on so far, but on the actual application I see this form (I have checked off some boxes already):

[image]

What is an "Options Account"? Do I need one? What are the benefits of having one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Options are a derivative product, and in this case, derive their value from an underlying security, a traded stock. An option gives you the right, but not the obligation, to buy a stock at a given price (the *strike* price) by a given time (the *expiration* date.) What I just described is a *call* option. The opposite instrument is a *put*, giving you the right, but not the obligation, to sell the stock at a given price.

Volumes have been written on the subject, but I'd suggest that for a custodial Roth, I'd not activate the ability to trade options.

*[How to get started with options investing?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10807/how-to-get-started-with-options-investing)* offers a nice introduction to trading options. In my response, I offer an example of a trade that's actually less risky due to the option component.

Comment: Used by an expert, options can be a way to "hedge" a bet on a stock, balancing risk against payoff. Used by a non-experts, options can be EXTREMELY risky. I agree with JoeTaxpayer that this is emphatically an area where if you have to ask, you not only don't need one but should actively avoid having one.

Comment: Note that options are available on all sorts of underlying securities, not just stocks.

Comment: @dg99 - absolutely. I wrote 'in this case' as the stock option is the OP's issue, but there are options on many other underlying assets. I joked to my wife that Life Insurance is a 'put' option. She submits the death cert for the strike price.

Comment: :)  Does TDAmeriTrade limit its trading to stocks?  (I don't know much about the retail brokerage industry.)

Comment: Schwab has a partner company they bought which trades commodities. No idea if TD does.

Comment: Actually I just called TDAmeritrade and they said that my money was put in to a money market account that accrues only .01% term interest, so it does look like you need to have an options account in order to make any money while you have a Roth IRA.

Comment: Where will they hold your cash if you agree to the options? The two shouldn't be related.

Comment: It looks like they don't *hold* you money in a different place, they just invest it in some different system. They referred me to another section of their website which lists different trading options for example mutual funds.

Comment: @Richard You are definitely getting things confused in a bad way. Your uninvested money goes into that money market, which does accrue basically nothing.  TD Ameritrade will let you buy stocks, bonds, CDs among other things, which is where you should focus.  Invest in some combination of those instead of holding the money market. As in JoeTaxpayer's answer you do not need to sign up for options trading. Based on your questions you *should not* at this point until you understand very well what they are and how to use them.